# Sidebar div not stretching vertically

Tags: html, css

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/up7Zg/1/) thus far.

What should I do to make sidebar stretch vertically (height) on the entire page? Right now it stretches to the original height of web browser window, but when there is more content inside the container, the sidebar does not stretch with it.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="sidebar">
            menu
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            ... a bunch of content ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS from the above JSFiddle:**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: please add relevant sections of your code to the question as well as referencing jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a "pure" css solution for this issue. The problem is that your sidebar is 100% height of it's parent container. And it's parent container `main-content` is 100% height of it's parent (*the window*). So for your `content` to be the same height as `main-content`'s inner content you would then have to set a pixel height value to `main-content`.

However you could easily resolve this with jquery.

```
var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
var content = $('.content');

if (content.height() > sidebar.height() )
    sidebar.css('height', content.height());
else
    sidebar.css('height', sidebar.height());
```

**Fiddles:**

http://jsfiddle.net/up7Zg/29/ and http://jsfiddle.net/up7Zg/30/

Comment: Thank You, Your answer looks like it is a resolution for me. But please, I don't know jquery. How to inject this jquery code into separated project than jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Good deal, glad to help!

Comment: Grrr, I was too fast. Kris - Your solution is ok, but look. When sidebar has more text than container. The background of the sidebar doesn't stretch but stays as high as container text. How to solve this?

Comment: Probably want to hide main-content's overflow: See http://jsfiddle.net/up7Zg/26/ and http://jsfiddle.net/up7Zg/25/

Comment: yes but look, there is still more text in sidebar than the background shows.

Comment: when u put overflow it cuts off the rest of text in sidebar.

Comment: ah I see what you are saying. I didn't see it cause the text was white.

Comment: This should work better: http://jsfiddle.net/up7Zg/29/ and http://jsfiddle.net/up7Zg/30/ Forget what I said about overflow.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;  /*  this line, and the one above, confer full-height */
    left: 0;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #f90; /* adjust to taste, just to see where the element was rendered */
}
```